# Devices not recognising my main Twitter account

Tags: twitter

I have three Twitter accounts but today I can only use two. The main account, that I use daily, now does not seem to be linked to the other two. When I go on to the Twitter app that account doesn’t appear. I can’t remember the original password I used to set up the main account so how can I reconnect the three?

Comment: Did you try login from any browser on desktop/laptop? Did you try forget password option?

Comment: Yes and I managed to reset the password so all three are now back up and hopefully linked. Thanks for getting in touch!